# 'At least one' Probability

Tags: probability

Sharpshooter A hits the target 1/4 of the time. Sharpshooter B hits the target 2/5 of the time. If they both shoot, what is the probability that at least one sharpshooter will hit the target?

Comment: What have you tried? I think you can model the two events as independent events, and then you can use the product rule.

Comment: Please show your thoughts, it is the way it works. What happens for instance if none of them hits the target? Which is the probability for this event?

Comment: Statistically, this question is a duplicate of about one hundred others on this site, not to mention the fact that it has no context and displays no efforts on your side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:
You can answer this question in two ways.

- Method 1: Prob A hits the target + Prob B hits the target + Both hit
  the target
- Method 2: 1 - P neither A nor B hit the target

Comment: Please do not encourage questions with no context or efforts by answering them.

Comment: Okay, sorry about it.

Comment: My answer was 11/20 but my teacher insist that the correct answer was 13/20

Answer (score 0):

Find the probability that A hits it and B does not hit it, so 1/4 x 3/5. Then find the probability that A does not hit it and B hits it, so 3/4 x 2/5. Last find the probability that A hits it and B hits it which is 1/4 x 2/5. Add all of these probabilities and that is your answer.